# If the last defender leaves the court, must the raider cross the baulk line?

Tags: rules, kabaddi

In the following kabbadi situation:

- There is one player left on team A
- Team B player goes for a raid
- Team A player leaves the court
- The team B player doesn't cross the baulk line

Will the team B player be given out for not crossing the baulk line?